# What are the exact steps towards remapping the Japanese keys on a Japanese keyboard in xkb?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am trying to remap the keys found on a Japanese keyboard to be Alt, Super, Return, and Shift. [Here is a good description](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-8.html) of the kind of keyboard I'm using. (I am actually using a Filco Majestouch 2 TKL Japanese keyboard). The idea is to have a perfectly normal English keyboard where the extra keys under the thumbs are remapped to Alt, Return, etc. I am doing this using xkb under Ubuntu.

The keyboard's bottom row looks like this:

```
<LCTL> <LWIN> <LALT> <MUHE> <SPCE> <HENK> <HKTG> <RALT> <MENU> <RCTL>
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
<LCTL> <LALT> <LWIN> <LALT> <SPCE> <RALT> <RTRN> <MENU> <RALT> <RCTL>
```

Remapping `LWIN`, `LALT`, `RALT`, and `MENU` worked, but remapping `MUHE`, `HENK`, and `HKTG` hasn't.

On top of this I tried remapping `AB11` to `Shift_R` and `AE13` to `BackSpace`. The result is that `AB11` does nothing just like `MUHE`, `HENK`, and `HKTG`, but `AE13` did get remapped to `BackSpace` and works as intended.

Until now I've been using the `basic` keycodes defined (as I understand) in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/xfree86`. Because of this, my keyboard layout's symbols file started like this:

```
default
xkb_symbols "basic" {
```

Since `MUHE`, `HENK`, `HKTG`, `AB11`, and `AE13` are defined in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev`, I assumed I should change that to `evdev`, but that did not help:

```
default
xkb_symbols "evdev" {
```

Is there anything else I need to do in order to use `MUHE` etc? Do I need to ensure some other part of the input system uses evdev? I am not sure how to do that. I am on Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit, but the same behavior happens on 18.04 64-bit.

Here is the full code I use to remap those keys (I omitted unrelated parts of the layout):

```
default
xkb_symbols "evdev" {
    // Swap Caps Lock and Escape.
    key <CAPS> {        [       Escape  ]       };
    // key <ESC>  {        [     Caps_Lock    ]       };
    key <ESC> { type[Group1]="TWO_LEVEL", [ Multi_key, Multi_key ] };

    key <LWIN> {
        type[Group1]="ONE_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1]=[        Alt_L ]
    };

    key <LALT> {
        type[Group1]="ONE_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1]=[        Super_L ]
    };

    key <MUHE> {
        type[Group1]="ONE_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1]=[        Alt_L ]
    };
    // placeholder for <SPCE>

    key <HENK> {
        type[Group1]="ONE_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1]=[        Alt_R ]
    };

    key <HKTG> {
        type[Group1]="ONE_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1]=[        Return ]
    };

    key <RALT> {
        type[Group1]="ONE_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1]=[        Menu ]
    };

    key <MENU> {
        type[Group1]="ONE_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1]=[        Alt_R ]
    };

    // LSGT is the extra key in the European layout that is found between the
    // left Shift and Z.
    key <LSGT> {
        type[Group1]="ONE_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1]=[        Super_L ]
    };


// Japanese keyboard bottom row:
// <LCTL> <LWIN> <LALT> <MUHE> <SPCE> <HENK> <HKTG> <RALT> <MENU> <RCTL>
// Desired bottom row:
// <LCTL> <LALT> <LWIN> <LALT> <SPCE> <RALT> <RTRN> <MENU> <RALT> <RCTL>

// Other extra Japanese keys:

// Between / and right shift: <AB11>
    key <AB11> {
        type[Group1]="ONE_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1]=[        Shift_R ]
    };

// Between = and Backspace: <AE13>
    key <AE13> {
        type[Group1]="ONE_LEVEL",
        symbols[Group1]=[        BackSpace ]
    };

// Modifier numbers:
// Mod1 = Alt
// Mod2 = Num_Lock
// Mod4 = Super
// Mod5 = ISO Level3 Shift
// Shift = Shift

// <AB11> is Shift
    modifier_map Shift { Shift_L, Shift_R };
// <LALT> is Super, <LSGT> is Super too
    modifier_map Mod4 { Super_L, Super_R };
// <MENU> is Alt, <LWIN> is Alt too
    modifier_map Mod1 { Alt_L, Alt_R };
// we map a bunch of keys to ISO Level3 Shift
    modifier_map Mod5 { ISO_Level3_Shift };
};
```

Edit: turns out the code I posted above is (mostly?) correct, however some mechanism in xkb that is meant for enabling "multimedia" keys and other "unusual" keys clobbers the mappings above. The bottom row buttons work now, but the `AB11` key still does not perform as an additional `Shift` key. Still, that is some progress.

[Here is a description of this "inet" clobbering happening](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=91042). The listing below shows that it happens in my case, too:

```
$ setxkbmap ef -print
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+ef+inet(evdev)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Note the bit that says: `xkb_symbols   { include "pc+ef+inet(evdev)"    };`. That means that it first applies the normal `pc` layout (US QWERTY), then whatever layout I have selected (here called `ef`, though I didn't call it that, I guess it's just a variable name that's reused for all layouts), and then `inet(evdev)` is applied. Inside `symbols/inet`, you can find this block:

```
xkb_symbols "evdev" {
    key <HKTG>   {      [ Hiragana_Katakana     ]       };
    key <HENK>   {      [ Henkan                ]       };
    key <MUHE>   {      [ Muhenkan              ]       };
```

and apparently this gets applied because my keyboard is an "inet keyboard"; in `rules/base` you can find this:

```
! $inetkbds = acer_c300 acer_ferrari4k acer_laptop \
...
              pc105 \
...
```

as well as further down this block:

```
  $inetkbds     =       +inet(%m)
```

So now the question is how to make my keyboard not get seen as an `inet` keyboard?

Or alternatively, could this be what's causing it? Inside `rules/evdev`, there is this block:

```
! model     =   symbols
  $evdevkbds    =   +inet(evdev)+inet(%m)
  applealu_jis  =   +inet(evdev)+macintosh_vndr/jp(alujiskeys)
  *             =   +inet(evdev)
```

The last line would apparently mean that no matter what keyboard you have, if you base your keyboard layout on `evdev` by doing `xkb_symbols "evdev" {`, you always get `inet(evdev)` added in the end, overriding your symbols.

I don't know xkb well enough to know which is the case, so some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I still don't know why I can't remap `AB11`. Is something still missing? I define `AB11` as `Shift_R` and then give it the `Shift` ability via `modifier_map Shift { Shift_L, Shift_R };`. Yet in `xev`, when I press this button, it does indeed get recognized as `Shift_R`, but state is still `0x0` (no modifiers), rather than `0x1` (Shift) which it should be:

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0xdc00001,
    root 0x1ef, subw 0x0, time 1701230053, (441,592), root:(444,729),
    state 0x0, keycode 97 (keysym 0xffe2, Shift_R), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 62
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

There doesn't seem to be anything overriding this key (or any other key with the same keycode) in `inet(evdev)`.

Comment: I think this may have something to do with the issue I am seeing: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=91042

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for pointing me out to the right direction. Finally after tinkering xkb for half day i can make it work. This is my configuration, please adjust according to your need:

This in in symbols/us:

xkb_symbols "basic" {

```
    ...
    key <AE13>   {[ BackSpace, BackSpace  ]};
    key <AB11>   {[ backslash,    bar     ]};
    key <BKSL>   {[ Return]};

};
```

This is in symbols/inet:

```
key <HKTG>   {      [ space         ]       };
key <HENK>   {      [ space         ]       };
key <MUHE>   {      [ space         ]       };
```

Cheers,
Winner